# Jest toMatchInlineSnapshot keep showing "operation not permitted, scandir message"

Tags: reactjs, jestjs, snapshot

I am trying to use `toMatchInlineSnapshot`, but it keeps showing `EPERM: operation not permitted, scandir`, `at traverseFolder (node_modules/prettier/index.js`. I guess it's related to writing data to file!? But if I use `toMatchSnapshot`, it works.
Could somebody give a hint?

Comment: The problem is specific to Prettier, toMatchSnapshot doesn't use it. You can debug specified traverseFolder function and check which paths it complains at.

Answer (score 0):

It turns out that I need to grant access to folders permission then prettier can traverseFolder without permission deny.